# Make certain cells unfocusable using ngGrid

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I am using ngGrid to display some data. Some of my fields are using a cell template to display an input field, whilst the others are not using any cell template.

ngGrid adds a `tabindex` attribute to the cells. I have removed this attribute from all the cells using jQuery (just testing in my browser console for now) that are not input fields in order to allow the user to just tab through the input fields in the row as well as tried setting the value of the attribute to `-1`. This does not seem to be respected as when I tab through the fields, the focus still goes to the columns that are labels.

The options for my ngGrid are below:

```
  $scope.model.gridOptions = {
        enableCellSelection: true,
        multiSelect: false,
        data: 'model.tests',

        columnDefs: [
            { field: 'field1', displayName: 'Field 1', width: '75px' },
            { field: 'field2', displayName: 'Field 2', width: '150px', cellTemplate: '<input ng-required="true" min=0  type="number" ng-model="COL_FIELD" ng-input="COL_FIELD">' },//A
            { field: 'field3', displayName: 'Field 3', width: '75px' },
            //More fields, a mix of input fields and labels

    };
```

**EDIT**:
If I remove the tabindex via a user action, such as a button, I get the behaviour i expect )(i.e. not being able to focus the field), however another issue occurs where the tab button does not let you go past the first non focusable element.

I have a created a `plunkr` demonstrating this [issue](http://plnkr.co/edit/c9Tzw7vnPebGhaH8HY9h?p=preview).

So, the question now is:

**Does anyone know how I can disable the non input fields from being focusable and still allow the user to tab past the non focusable elements?**

**UPDATE**:
After looking a bit closer at the ngGrid code, it seems that `tab` keydown events are captured by the grid and some special handling is attempted. I tried a few different things and managed to get some of the behaviour I wanted working however it ended up breaking the `Shift + Tab` behaviour

Comment: this is strange. [wc3](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#adef-tabindex) docs say

"The following elements support the tabindex attribute: A, AREA, BUTTON, INPUT, OBJECT, SELECT, and TEXTAREA."

ng-grid puts tabindex on ... like everything.

well, maybe you could use [beforeSelectionChange](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/#api) event and set your focus programmatically to the next element.

Comment: @link64: When an element has class="ngSelectionCell" it will not receive a tabindex of 0 nor will any existing tabindexes be overwritten. This is hardcoded in ngGridDirectives.directive('ngCell'... (around line 2650 in ng-grid.js). Still, I'm not sure how this might help us.

Answer (score 0):

You can use these below property and comment your remove tab index with 2.0.14 ng-grid version. Tabbing will work as expected
tabIndex: 0, 
noTabInterference: true